# how to make an Android RecyclerView Load More, Endless Scrolling with progress bar(half visible)?

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview

I have made a endless scrolling with using progress bar with recycle view and also use fire-store for data retrieving. My problem is, the progress bar is not at appropriate position/visible(half visible) on the screen.
here below I have pasted my code:

**activity_main.xml**

this is activity main XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/isLoading"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/isLoadingMore"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/recyclerView" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
        android:focusable="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

this is main activity JAVA file.

```
package com.IUDV;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.IUDV.Adapters.NotesShowsAdapter;
import com.IUDV.models.NoteShow;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.CollectionReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.Query;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private final List<NoteShow> noteShows = new ArrayList<>();
    private NotesShowsAdapter notesShowsAdapter;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private ProgressBar loadingPB, loadingMorePB;
    private int limit = 15;
    private DocumentSnapshot lastVisible;
    private boolean isScrolling = false;
    private boolean isLastItemReached = false;
    private FirebaseFirestore rootRef;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        loadingPB = findViewById(R.id.isLoading);
        loadingMorePB = findViewById(R.id.isLoadingMore);
        notesShowsAdapter = new NotesShowsAdapter(noteShows);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(notesShowsAdapter);
        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

            }
        });
        rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        CollectionReference productsRef = rootRef.collection("notes");
        Query query = productsRef.orderBy("title", Query.Direction.ASCENDING).limit(limit);
        loadingPB.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        query.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                        noteShows.add(new NoteShow(document.get("id").toString(),document.get("title").toString(),document.get("description").toString()));
                    }
                    notesShowsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    loadingPB.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    lastVisible = task.getResult().getDocuments().get(task.getResult().size() - 1);

                    RecyclerView.OnScrollListener onScrollListener = new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
                            if (newState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL) {
                                isScrolling = true;
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

                            LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = ((LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager());
                            int firstVisibleItemPosition = linearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
                            int visibleItemCount = linearLayoutManager.getChildCount();
                            int totalItemCount = linearLayoutManager.getItemCount();

                            if (isScrolling && (firstVisibleItemPosition + visibleItemCount == totalItemCount) && !isLastItemReached) {
                                loadingMorePB.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                isScrolling = false;
                                Query nextQuery = productsRef.orderBy("title", Query.Direction.ASCENDING).startAfter(lastVisible).limit(limit);
                                nextQuery.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> t) {
                                        if (t.isSuccessful()) {
                                            for (DocumentSnapshot d : t.getResult()) {
                                                noteShows.add(new NoteShow(d.get("id").toString(),d.get("title").toString(),d.get("description").toString()));
                                            }
                                            notesShowsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                            loadingMorePB.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                            lastVisible = t.getResult().getDocuments().get(t.getResult().size() - 1);

                                            if (t.getResult().size() < limit) {
                                                isLastItemReached = true;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    };
                    recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(onScrollListener);
                }else {
                    loadingPB.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**NoteShow.java**

this is model file.

```
package com.IUDV.models;

public class NoteShow {

    private String id;
    private String title;
    private String description;

    public NoteShow(String id, String title, String description) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

**NotesShowsAdapter.java**

this is Adapter file

```
package com.IUDV.Adapters;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.IUDV.R;
import com.IUDV.models.NoteShow;

import java.util.List;

public class NotesShowsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NotesShowsAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private List<NoteShow> noteShowList;

    public NotesShowsAdapter(List<NoteShow> noteShowList) {
        this.noteShowList = noteShowList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public NotesShowsAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.view_layout, parent, false);
        return new NotesShowsAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull NotesShowsAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.txtTitle.setText(noteShowList.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.txtDesc.setText(noteShowList.get(position).getDescription());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return noteShowList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView txtTitle;
        private TextView txtDesc;
        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            txtTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textTitle);
            txtDesc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textDesc);
        }
    }
}
```

**view_layout.xml**

this is item layout file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/background_note"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textDesc"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Description"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textTitle" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the progress bar is not at appropriate position/visible(half visible)"?

Comment: it means the progress bar is visible half on the screen its like the progress bar position has shifted below the screen a little

Comment: So it's most likely a UI issue rather than a Firebase one, right?

Comment: any idea how can solved

Comment: yes,like ui issue and query will perfect worked.